# Regression predicting 2 dependent variables

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-regression

Imagine I have a big dataset $\textbf{X}$ that constitutes my independent variables and I want to predict a vector of 2 components, $\mathbf{Y} = (y_1, y_2)$. A regression will be something like $\mathbf{Y} = f(\textbf{X}, \textbf{W})$, with $\textbf{W}$ the weights or coefficients and $f$ a function that can be linear or highly non-linear.

I know how to do the regression for each $y_i$ (with $f_i$ and in general $f_1 \neq f_2$), but does it exist a way to do the regression **simultaneously**, that is, predicting a vector of 2 components instead of predicting a scalar value?

Comment: Try the [`multivariate-regression`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariate-regression?sort=votes) tag. We have many questions relating to it.

Comment: In econometrics this is called "seemingly unrelated regression". Try googling that.

Comment: Sometimes simultaneous estimation is not required. See my other answer. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328797/why-do-we-use-vector-autoregressive-models/328933#328933. Other times simultaneous estimation is performed by stacking the data into a special matrix form and solving it (Seemingly Unrelated Regression).

Answer (score 1):

PLS2 and multivariate multiple linear regression allow modelling of a set of dependent variables. The advantage of a single model for multiple predictors is that the model can use relationships between the dependent variables. For example PLS2 reduces the variance in both X and Y then the covariance between these two blocks.