# Estimating a VAR using OLS vs GLS

Tags: least-squares, vector-autoregression, generalized-least-squares

I have read in several places that I can estimate a VAR model equation by equation using OLS instead of using GLS, if I have the same explanatory variables.

Do I need to make any assumptions about the error terms in order for this to stand?

Does anyone have a reference to a proof in layman's terms?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328797/why-do-we-use-vector-autoregressive-models/328933#328933

Comment: @CowboyTrader thanks but I do see this as a different question and the linked answers not to answer the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinary least squares is a specific case of the general least squares regression. The basic assumption is that **the error terms in OLS have to be homoscedastic and are uncorrelated**. These assumptions are sometimes very hard. If e.g. you estimate an OLS with heteroscedastic errors then your estimator remains unbiased but is not efficient anymore. The GLS estimation instead leads to BLUE estimator under heteroscedastic residuals.

Another approach to deal with heteroscedastic and serial correlated errors would be to use special standard errors in your OLS estimation. (see [here](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/15-4-hac-standard-errors.html))

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. One last question, if I estimate the equation line by line, why would it matter as I am not directly linking the error term in the first equation to the second equation?

Comment: how would the LS estimate even consider the second error term. I know its probably simple but I need this spelling out. I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: Are you speaking about a VAR model? I each term uses the other variables as regressors. A shock in y1 will influence y2 because y1 is used to explain y2.

Comment: Yes, I am speaking about a VAR one model. Specifically, lets say the conditional variances of y1 and y2 are correlated. I would, therefore, expect least squares to have size distortion. However, how could the correlation between the error terms be picked up in line by line estimation?

Comment: Each equation uses all variable or at least lags of each variable. Therefore the error term of each error influences all variables.

Comment: @JackSalah, given the same set of regressors in each equation, OLS and GLS **are the same thing** – they are equivalent, see [a Wkikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions#Equivalence_to_OLS). So whatever properties one has, the other will have, too. The answer by Martin seems to refer to versions of GLS encountered in univariate settings, I beieve, but these do not apply in your case. So I think the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I refered to the univariate setting. But I thought it could be extended to a multivariate case. When the residuals are correlated or heteroscedastic shouldn´t the standard errors differ between OLS and GLS? So the right choice would be based on the assumptions about the error term?